# How to Insert 1.2 million of Insert Command having in .sql file

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have .sql file which contains 1200000 Insert command.,
When I am executing by opening in SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT it says

```
Insufficient memory to continue the execution of program
```

I was thinking to execute directly command prompt but facing Issue tried this `sqlcmd -d database Name -i fileName.sql`

please Help.

Comment: The problem could be single transacion. Try to split by 1000 inserts and commit each 1000 inserted.

Comment: Do you have a single transaction with 1.2m inserts?

Comment: yes it is single transaction .

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is

1. To first import the file in the database
2. Run each statement as a dynamic sql statement

**For Step 1**

You can try with [bulk insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365%28SQL.90%29.aspx) like the following

```
BULK INSERT dbo.temp 
FROM 'c:\temp\file.txt'
WITH 
(
    ROWTERMINATOR ='\n'
)
```

You can also use `OPENROWSET` like

```
SELECT BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'c:\temp\mytxtfile.txt', SINGLE_CLOB) MyFile
```

The following link gives more details

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1643/using-openrowset-to-read-large-files-into-sql-server/

Or if nothing of the above works you can create an `SSIS package` and try to import the file into a table.

**For Step 2**

Finally once the insert statements are in a table, loop the table to execute the insert statements with `BEGIN TRANSACTION` and `COMMIT` statement.

You would need to execute your statements using dynamic sql with the help of `EXEC` or `sp_executesql`. The following link will guide you with the same.

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/

Hope this helps

Comment: Based on the use of the `sqlcmd` statement in the question, The "filename.sql" file appears to contain actual SQL statements, not data.

Comment: @Jon Egerton I was coming to that point. Please see my updated answer. Sorry if I have misled a few. :)

Comment: BULK INSERT [databaseName].[tableName] FROM 'filePath\filename.sql'
WITH
(
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)   It says invalid objectname 'databaseName.tableName'

Comment: dbo is a schema name and not database name. You would need databasename.schemaname.tablename. Also I think you would need admin rights to run it so please check. If this is not working then simplest way is to create a dummy SSIS package and run it. To create an SSIS package to import a simple file should not take more than 20 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

For MySQL

Option 1 : On ubuntu, linux and mac system terminal command as below

```
$ mysql -uuser -p < /path/to/your/file.sql
OR
$ mysql -uuser -p -e "source /path/to/your/file.sql"
```

Option 2 : on Windows system try below commands

```
C:\> mysql -uuser -p < H:/path/to/your/file.sql
OR
C:\> mysql -uuser -p -e "source H:/path/to/your/file.sql"
```

Before try above commands need to upload a file on server or local machine, commands accepts file from local only of server not external path

For MsSQL import from .sql file

```
sqlcmd -S .\SQLEXPRESS -E -i "C:\path\file.sql"
```

import for .csv file

```
BULK INSERT tablename
    FROM 'C:\CSVData\filename.csv'
    WITH
    (
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  --CSV field delimiter
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',   --Use to shift the control to next row
    ERRORFILE = 'C:\CSVDATA\ImportErrorRows.csv',
    TABLOCK
    )
```

Comment: I thik mysql is "MySQL" command not for MSSQL , please guide,

Comment: yes, my first answer is for MySQL and just now i have updated for MsSQL.... if you are use MSSQL...than try sqlcmd -S .\SQLEXPRESS -E -i "C:\path\file.sql"

Comment: @Programmer-->I tried 2nd command "C:\>sqlcmd -S .\MSSQL -U username -
P password -i C:\2.sql -o C:\abc.txt" error was **Shared Memory Provider: No process is on the other end of the pipe**.

Communication link failure

Comment: @Programmer--> if I trying same command with less insert command then working properly.. which is my problem I have to execute all 12lac Insert command at one go